# HTML table bottom border of table head is missing

Tags: html, html-table, border, border-collapse

If I use border-collapse: collapse; for the table in my PDF,
the bottom border of my table head is missing.

[Table head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PR7rY.png)

My code:

```
<style>
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        overflow-wrap: anywhere;
    }

    table th {
        border: 2px solid #000;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 4px;
    }

    table td {
        border: 2px solid #000;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 4px;
    }

    .page_break {
        page-break-before: always;
    }
</style>


<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Test</th>
        <th>Test</th>
        <th>Test</th>
        <th>Test</th>
        <th>Test</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
```

....

How can I fix that error?

Comment: I can't reproduce it either with the above code. Do you have any other CSS, maybe in an external stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

lol bro you need to close the table.

```
<style>
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        overflow-wrap: anywhere;
    }

    table th {
        border: 2px solid #000;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 4px;
    }

    table td {
        border: 2px solid #000;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 4px;
    }

    .page_break {
        page-break-before: always;
    }
</style>


<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Test</th>
        <th>Test</th>
        <th>Test</th>
        <th>Test</th>
        <th>Test</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: I closed the table below.
The problem occurs as long as there is no data in the tbody yet.